# Missing required parameter for Route (not standard problem)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

A common problem is "Missing required parameter for Route", but I have a slightly different one, the solution to which I simply cannot find:

Here are my associated routes:

```
Route::get('/monitoring/{monitoring}/edit', [HistoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('monitoring.edit');
Route::patch('/monitoring/{monitoring}', [HistoryController::class, 'update'])->name('monitoring.update');
```

usual update route according to laravel documentation

Here is the required part of the controller:

```
public function edit(History $history) {
    return view('monitoring.edit', compact('history'));        
}
public function update(History $history, Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'blablabla1' => 'integer',
        'blablabla2' => 'string',
        'blablabla3' => 'string',
        'blablabla4' => 'string',
    ]);
    dd($data);
}
```

and the view:

```
<form class="container" action="{{route('monitoring.update', $history)}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('patch')
...
```

I didn’t invent anything, I’m just “following the textbook”, but I get an error that occurs when there is no argument - in my case the argument is explicitly indicated. What's wrong?

**EDITED**:
there are logs - https://flareapp.io/share/x5MwLdDP

all my routes:

```
Route::get('/monitoring', [HistoryController::class, 'index'])->name('monitoring.index');
Route::get('/monitoring/create', [HistoryController::class, 'create'])->name('monitoring.create');
Route::get('/monitoring/{monitoring}/edit', [HistoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('monitoring.edit');
Route::patch('/monitoring/{monitoring}', [HistoryController::class, 'update'])->name('monitoring.update');
Route::get('/monitoring/deleting', [HistoryController::class, 'deleteData'])->name('monitoring.deleteData');
Route::post('/monitoring', [HistoryController::class, 'store'])->name('monitoring.store');

Route::get('/monitoring/sending', [HistoryController::class, 'setData']);
Route::get('/monitoring/updating', [HistoryController::class, 'updateData']);

Route::get('/monitoring/{monitoring}', [HistoryController::class, 'show'])->name('monitoring.show');
```

dd($history) in controller/blade:

```
#connection: null
  #table: "histories"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:1 [▼
    "deleted_at" => "datetime"
  ]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: []
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

and button in "show" with link to edit "any post":

```
<div class="dropdown position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 mb-3 me-3 bd-mode-toggle">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="float-end mb-1">
          <a href="{history}/edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-top:20px;">Изменить</button></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is part of show.blade.php view:

```
<main>
  @php
    $index = $requireID - 1;
    $state =  $allEntries[$index]['State'];

    if ($state == 1) {
      $state = "Установлена";
      $color = "#beface";
    }
    else {
      $state = "Не установлена";
      $color = "#fc2d2d";
    }
  @endphp
</table>
  <div class="container col-xs-12 col-md-5" style="margin-top:100px; font-size:18px; text-align: center">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover align-items-center">
  <h2 class="mb-5">Дополнительная информация о метке {{$allEntries[$index]['RFID']}}</h2>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">Свойство</th>
        <th scope="col">Значение</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>Состояние</td>
        <td style="background-color: {{$color}}">{{$state}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Метка</td>
        <td>{{$allEntries[$index]['RFID']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Номер станка</td>
        <td>{{$allEntries[$index]['ID_stanok']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Смыкания</td>
        <td>{{$allEntries[$index]['Count']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Предназначение</td>
        <td>{{$addInf[$index]['Purpose']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Производитель</td>
        <td>{{$addInf[$index]['Country']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Добавлена</td>
        <td>{{$allEntries[$index]['created_at']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Обновлена</td>
        <td>{{$allEntries[$index]['updated_at']}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 mb-3 me-3 bd-mode-toggle">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="float-end mb-1">
          <a href="{history}/edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-top:20px;">Изменить</button></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

<script src="/docs/5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `{{route('monitoring.update', ['monitoring' => $history])}}` as stated in [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Comment: Can you post the error/logs as well?

Comment: @brombeer, yew i tried - nothing is changed :(

Comment: What does `dd($history);` in your controller return? What does `@dd($history)` in your blade return?

Comment: @rizqyhi here is, please https://flareapp.io/share/LPd1Azp7#stack

Comment: @brombeer, in controller dd($history) returns me empty collection:
```
App\Models\History {#322 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\HistoryController.php:66
  #connection: null
  #table: "histories"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
...
``` 
in blade the same

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post/append relevant data there, not in the comments. Thanks

Comment: @brombeer, got it

Comment: Fix your HTML: `<button>` inside `<a>` [is invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#technical_summary) - and won't submit your form. `<a href="{history}/edit">` should also not work in blade, that should be `<a href="{{$history}}/edit">`. But as mentioned, remove the `<a>` part from that button

Comment: @brombeer, i I removed the button completely, now i have ```<a href="{{$history}}/edit">Изменить</a>```
but how is this supposed to help?

Comment: "_I removed the button completely_" Why? I suggested to "_remove the <a> part from that button_" - that is, leave the button as is - so you can actually submit your form

Comment: @brombeer, i'm sorry, is this what you meant?
```<form action="{{$history}}/edit">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
   </form>
```

Comment: It should be  

```<a href="{{ route('monitoring.edit', $history) }}">Изменить</a>```

Comment: @ShakilAlam, well, now I have this problem here too xD

Comment: <a href="/monitoring/{{ $history->id }}/edit">Изменить</a>

would work but it is a shortcut and you won't be able to use route nam

Answer (score 2):

You should tr

Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose **type-hinted variable** names match a **route segment name**.

Here you can try two things.

Approach 1:

You can update the route as

```
Route::get('/monitoring/{history}/edit', [HistoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('monitoring.edit');
Route::patch('/monitoring/{history}', [HistoryController::class, 'update'])->name('monitoring.update');
```

Approach 2:
You can rename variables in the Controller

```
public function edit(History $monitoring) {
    return view('monitoring.edit', compact('monitoring'));        
}
public function update(History $monitoring, Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'blablabla1' => 'integer',
        'blablabla2' => 'string',
        'blablabla3' => 'string',
        'blablabla4' => 'string',
    ]);
    dd($data);
}
```

I hope it helps. Also, make sure there aren't duplicate routes, you forgot to mention.

Comment: thanks, but anyway doesnt work.
i have no duplicate routes, but now i just get 404

Comment: Can you reshare the routes,  controller, model, view and error log

Comment: ofc, i edited the question, there are logs, controller, view, all routes.
in model i just have connection with my table in DB

Comment: public function update(History $history, Request $request) { should be public function update(Request $request, History $history) {

Comment: I swapped these arguments, nothing is changed

Comment: It seems like Issue is with view file only, Please reshare view and error

Comment: I added view, please, check him

Comment: <a href="/monitoring/{{ $history->id }}/edit">Изменить</a> would work but it is a shortcut and you won't be able to use route name

It seems like issue is with view only